# Select data in mysql where delimiters are two data alphanumeric data fields

Tags: mysql

My Table structure have two Columns, One for start range and another for End of Range.
Both are alphanumeric.
I have to search a row according to user input, a Alphanumeric string.

like : 
SELECT form table where range1 <= 'user_input' and range2 >= 'user_input';

But range1, range2 and user_input are alphanumeric values (Barcodes).

range1 and range2 are alphanumeric numbers generated by some php function in a series.

like for range1 156WB562789 and range2 156WB562880

range1 and range2 have change in last 3 chars (which are numbers) only remain all are same.

Comment: Can you describe how you want the comparison to work? What format are the strings? For example, are they hex codes? Can you give some examples of what you want?

Comment: They are like range1 = 1605WD16854  range2 = 1605WD16908 (range1 < range2)

Comment: How are these values typically compared? I.e., what makes range1 < range2? Is it an ordinary lexicographical order?

Comment: yes, they are in ordinary lexicographical order. i explain how in my question just edited

Comment: In that case what's the problem with simply comparing them like you have in your example query? That works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your barcode has always the same structure (`[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}`) you can split it into 3 cols (`part1` `part2` `part3` ) and then split user's string and make a query that will operate with that three cols.

It is not optimal solution but I have no other right now.